# PHP: Some parts of Token in URL will be replaced by other Chars in generated HTML eMail

Tags: php, html-email

im developing a Login-System and one Step of it is, that a Token will be generated in PHP, stored in DB and placed in a eMail with a Login-Link. At my local xampp windows machine its working perfectly. If i try it on my Webserver, i get a issue:

- Random parts of my Login-Link will be replaced by other Chars. I observed, that its only appears in Token-Part of the Login-Link. So i think there is some issue with the charset maybe?

Code Part for generating Token and send it by eMail:

```
<?php
 // Create Token
 $user_logintoken = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));

// Create eMail Content
  $to= "user@email.com;
  $subject = "Login Link";
  $loginurl = "https://www.website.com/index.php?page=login&token=".$user_logintoken;
  $message= "Hi User \r\n".
  "to Login, use this Link:\r\n
  <a href=\"".$loginurl."\">".$loginurl."</a>\r\n";
        
   $header = 'From: admin@email.com' . "\r\n" .
             'Reply-To: admin@email.com' . "\r\n" .
             'Mime-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
             'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n" .
             'Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable' . "\r\n" .
             'X-Mailer: PHP ' . phpversion();
// Send eMail
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
?>
```

So for example:

```
$user_logintoken = "e25790f817421cee485074856df12ca4"
```

In the HTML eMail i got:

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?page=login&token�5790f817421cee485074856df12ca4
```

In HTML eMail Source Code, everythink is fine:

```
https://www.website.com/index.php?page=login&amp;token=e25790f817421cee485074856df12ca4
```

So i think there is an issue with encoding... i already tried htmlentities($loginurl), urlencode($loginurl) and rawurlencode($loginurl) but its not fixing my problem.

Can anyone please help me ? :-)

Comment: Is it always the '=' after token that get messed, or this happens to other char too?

Comment: My suggestion (and maybe this solve your problem) is to never user php mail() function. Composing mail by hand in terms of header, attachment and so on is cumbersome. Better use php library like symfony/mailer: https://github.com/symfony/mailer or PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Hi Roberto, its every time '=' missing. Another Example `index.php?page=login&token8fcc37bbfc95c5ff93f1ea8527dab0`  <- not appering here in Comment box, but in the eMail i see a "Arrow Up"-Sign between "token" and "8fcc..:"